# Implement a ListView with dynamic section

Tags: android, listview

Does anyone have any suggestion or Open Source project to implement a ListView like the following image? I don't even know how to call it, to do a nice search (Searching for ListView with dynamic sections I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/)).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image in question is of an Expandable List View (which is a built-in view). Expandable list views allow you to style the groups and children differently and handles expanding/contracting the groups.

Look at http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html for more information